# Graph database: get common parent node

Tags: dgraph

I want to select the first common boss for two employees in draph.

My model is simple:

name: string
boss_of: uids

Lets assume the following data where each arrow denotes the boss_of edge:

```
A -> B
A -> C
B -> D
C -> E
E -> F
E -> G
```

So, given F And D the query should return A, for F and G the result is obviously E.

I tried using `allofterms` but found no solution as there may be a different number of nodes
between the co-workers and their common boss. Is it possible at all to formulate such a query?

I am trying to explore dgraph (or graph databases at all), so maybe I am just overseeing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use K-Shortest [Path Queries](https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#k-shortest-path-queries)

The middle one in the response is the closest common entity.